# Error: Components.utils undefined - Firefox Add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, import, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox add-on (using add-on SDK) and I need to use cookies. In order to do that I should import the ["Services.jsm"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm) module.

I have followed the instructions from MDN, which advises to use

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

I also tried:

```
Components.utils["import"]("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

When using both I get:

```
- _errorType = TypeError
- message = Components.utils is undefined
```

Does any one know how to solve this?

References:
[Components.utils.import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.import)

Comment: are you using the add-on sdk or developing a bootstrapped extension? Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

Comment: I am using the add-on sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Addon-on SDK, you have to import it this way:

```
const { Cu } = require("chrome");
let Services = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

See https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/02/16/using-jsm-modules-in-the-sdk/ for more details.